# Parsing two json data and displaying it together

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to parse two given sets of json data, which are:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json

Now i want to display it in an angularjs view in a table form by getting it through an http service. I know how to display data provided by one url but what to do if there are two given urls and data should be displayed together? I've read that it could be achieved by $q but i cant understand how to use it. Please help. For one url, this is a solution.

```js
this.baseUrl = 'some url';
this.loadAllBlogs = function() {

  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: main.baseUrl + '/all'
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log(response);
    main.blogs = response.data.data;
    console.log(main.blogs);

  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    alert("some error occurred. Check the console.");
    console.log(response);

  });


}
```

What to do when there are two urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and pass in an array of the request promises.

The data array in `$q.all().then()` will be in same order as requests in the requests array

```
  var urls = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2015-16/en.1.json',
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfootball/football.json/master/2016-17/en.1.json'
  ];

  // map array of `$http` promises
  let requests = urls.map((url) => $http.get(url).then((resp) => resp.data));

  $q.all(requests).then((dataArr) => {
      console.log(dataArr);// in same order as urls
  }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log('Something went wrong with requests');
      console.log(err);
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ipwFEPana5xfKEU7jQtz?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the solution, It works. But i also mentioned i have a little problem in understanding $q in particular. What does it do?

Comment: It is an internal promise library. Is same promises that `$http` uses and calls `$apply()` so that if used to update scope angular will run digests. Explained in docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q